# My login.php does not appear to be working

Tags: php, html, authentication

Im currently working on a very basic login system, which I know it not the best way to do so, but at the minute I just want to make sure I'm getting the hang of it.. my login.php looks as so..

```
<?php

        session_start();

        $the_username = "xxxx";
        $the_password = "12345";

        if ($_POST['username'] == $the_username ) &&
            ($_POST['password'] == $the_password) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: menu.php");
        }

        else { echo "Entry Denied"; return;}
    ?>
```

And my form looks like so..

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST" >
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input type="submit" name="Login" class="login" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Could someone shed some light on why this does not appear to be working?

Answer (score 1):

`$username` is empty but `$_POST['username']` is what you looking for

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I'm not quite sure what you mean here

Comment: $_SESSION['username'] = $username; //where is $username coming from

Comment: Thank you, that turned out not to be the issue, but instead I wasn't running my form.html through xampp!

Comment: please dont accept wrong answers as it will mislead other people with the same questions.

Comment: It is clear now thank you @bub... I had made a typo. I wanted to set the session variable as $the_username, which I hadn't, instead I was setting it as $username which I hadn't declared. <-- That is what I believe was occurring anyway.

Comment: @JordanFrampton and why didi you accept the answer first and unaccept it today?